# How do you manually extract (decapsulate) an H.264 bitstream from an MP4 file

Tags: video, h.264, mp4

Would extracting an H264 bitstream from an MP4 is achieved just by appending all raw data from a video track in an H.264 MP4 file, or is there some special decoding steps to realize?

There are some H.264 decoder sources here and there that take a pure "264" track as input. Is this input directly readable / available from the average MP4 file? (Let's say the common iOS or Windows Phone MP4 AVC file type.)

Comment: Note from my two years old older myself: Dear smaller me: yes, this is the same data inside the chunks. But don't bother with it, there are easily portable libraries like mp4parser, and even better, ffmpeg compiled for most platforms out there. If you are adventurous, read about NAL Units and SPS/PSS, and make some tests with ffmpeg in command line to compare the data of an .mp4 with the bare .264 stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is known as multiplexing: you extract individual stream from a file with possibly multiple streams and additional information.

In Windows, Media Foundation API offers [MPEG-4 File Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read and demultiplex `.MP4` files. There are third party demultiplexers for DirectShow API as well, e.g. [from GDCL](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/).

FFmpeg's `libavformat` has its own demultiplexer.

Comment: When I copy - let's say 100 bytes - from the .264 file and I search it in the original H.264 file, it is there. So in which sense is this multiplexing expression used?

Comment: Btw, with some hex editor verification, it really seems that the .263 file (bitstream) is contained integrally in the original MP4 file.

Comment: Things multiplexing allows: `1` 2+ synchronizes streams within a file (e.g. video+audio), `2` time stamped streams, `3` seek-friendly streams, esp. those with index in the beginning of the file, progressive download friendly. With all this, demultiplexing still gives original bitstream.